# Passing an array to a javascript function from objc

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, ios5

I am trying to send an array to a javascript function via objective C.

I call the javascript function from my code by -

```
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
```

I am now trying to pass an array of values to the javascript function.

This is what I tried -

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10",@"9",@"8", nil];
     string = [[array valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];        

    [graphView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName2(%@)", string]];
}
```

In my Javascript -

```
        <script>
            function methodName(val)
            {
                alert(val);
            }
        </script>
```

However, only the number 10 gets displayed on my alert message on the webview. So I feel I am doing something wrong. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
And also, I would need to convert that string back into an array in the javascript.

It would be great if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: It would be great if this could be accomplished by passing an object, not just a string.  Oh well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName2([%@])", string]
```

Comment: that worked!!! thank you very much.. would you be able to tell me why that worked though?

Comment: Also, I need to convert the string back into an array in javascript.. when I tried to use the 'split' function, it is not working.. is it because of the way I am passing the "String" to the javascript?

Comment: @learner2010, in the above code your variable "val" is already an array. No need to split it.